# How to do a floor_date() in dbplyr

Tags: r, sql-server, dplyr, tidyverse, dbplyr

I'm trying to aggregate minute-level time series data to hourly level via averaging.

In order to do that I want to calculate an hour column that has the day and hour that the reading occurred in. Then I can do a simple `group_by` `summarise`. For instance, my `tbl_df` looks like:

```
# Database: Microsoft SQL Server 13.00.4001[<SERVER>/<Project>]
   eGauge                    time Channel        End_Use Metric Circuit     Reading mean_lag
    <int>                   <chr>   <chr>          <chr>  <chr>   <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>
 1  30739 2018-07-06 20:04:00.000     8.0 Clothes Washer      P    <NA> 0.000033333       60
 2  30739 2018-07-06 20:13:00.000     3.0  Clothes Dryer      P    <NA> 0.000833333       60
 3  30739 2018-07-06 21:16:00.000     6.0        Cooktop      P    <NA> 0.000050000       60
 4  30739 2018-07-06 21:00:00.000     3.0  Clothes Dryer      P    <NA> 0.000833333       60
 5  30739 2018-07-06 21:46:00.000     8.0 Clothes Washer      P    <NA> 0.000016667       60
 6  30739 2018-07-07 02:06:00.000     3.0  Clothes Dryer      P    <NA> 0.001016667        1
 7  30739 2018-07-07 08:52:00.000     1.0  Service Mains      P    <NA> 1.814516667        1
 8  30739 2018-07-07 08:52:00.000     3.0  Clothes Dryer      P    <NA> 0.001050000        1
 9  30739 2018-07-07 08:52:00.000     4.0     Central AC      P    <NA> 0.043000000        1
10  30739 2018-07-07 08:52:00.000     5.0           Oven      P    <NA> 0.021333333        1
```

and I would like a new column like this: `2018-07-06 20:00:00.000` or `2018-07-06 20:00:00.000`.

Normally I would use `floor_date(time, "hour")` from `lubridate`, or even `str_replace(time, ".{2}(?=:[^:]*$)", "00")`, but neither are working for me with my SQL Server connection.

Any idea how this is done in R? Answer must R code and preferrably be dplyr code such as:

```
# NOT WORKING
my_table %>%
  mutate(time_hour = floor_date(time, "hour"))
```

or

```
# NOT WORKING
my_table %>%
  mutate(time_hour = DATEADD('hour', DATEDIFF('hour', 0, time), 0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
my_table %>%
    mutate(time_hour = DATEADD(sql("hour"), DATEDIFF(sql("hour"), 0, time), 0))
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this, it looks much better. I don't have the ability to test the solution at this time, but giving this answer the benefit of the doubt. If the next one who comes across this can upvote/comment to confirm this works I'd be obliged.

Answer (score 0):

## WORKS BUT NEEDS IMPROVEMENT

```
my_table %>%
      mutate(hour = "hour",
             time_hour = DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, time), 0)) %>%
      select(-hour)
```

Comment: How come that your own answer be the solution, although it needs improvement?

Comment: It had been a few weeks and this is the best I found. If anyone has a better solution I'm happy to mark their solution as best instead :)